# How to re-assign ForeignKey in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have two following models:

```
 class Student(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text='Name of student')

 class Group(models.Model):
         name = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="Groups' name")
         elder = models.ForeignKey(Student, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
```

The case is that I have form(created from modelForm) which is able to update entries in database. My problem is following:
User can create two groups with ForeignKey that will point to one entry in `Student` table.

I've found `db_constraint` in documentation but it seems like not enough.
It will be great to get following behavior:
When user assigns ForeignKey which is already assigned to another model, I want to delete old assignment and create new. So `Student` Foreign key could be assigned only to one model at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

override the `save` method of `Group`:

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
     Group.objects.filter(elder.self.elder).update(elder=None)
     super(Group, self).save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
```

but you must use transactions to avoid inconsistency

Comment: Thanks for idea. I decided not to add such complexity like overriding built-in methods, but just make this query `Group.objects.filter(elder_id=new_elder.id).update(elder=None)` prior saving form and it works perfectly.

Comment: overriding save() in django is common. the 'internal' method is save_base()

Answer (score 1):

The `OneToOneField` is specifically designed for unique relations:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="Groups' name")

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text='Name of student')
    group = models.OneToOneField(Group, default=None, blank=True, null=True, related_name='elder')
```

Note how I moved the relationship field to the `Student` model, this will give you the behaviour that you want. If it was on the `Group` model, and you assign a student to a new group while he already has one, it would raise a `DatabaseError` for violating the `unique` constraint. In this case, the (unique) `FOREIGN KEY` column is in the `Student`'s table, so if you assign a student to another group and save that group, the student table will be updated and the old group replaced.